# Error management not working

Tags: freeze, galaxy

I'm an android developer. I acquired recently a Samsung Galaxy S3 (I9300) and I am having some problems with it.

The error management doesn't work. I mean, when an app crashes, it doesn't show "Force close",  the phone just freezes.

I had an HTC before; I use it when I'm developing too, and with the same malfunctioning app, my HTC shows me force close, but the S3 freezes and I have to restart it.
As you can imagine, this is very annoying.

I found a temporary solution, but it affects wifi.  Using this app

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.issess.fastforceclose&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5pc3Nlc3MuZmFzdGZvcmNlY2xvc2UiXQ..

and enabling "old fast force close" seems to solve the problem, but it has wifi related problems.

### Things I have tried

- Clean ROM, wiping data and Dalvik cache (it works at the beginning, but suddenly the phone freezes and when I restart, the error management doesn't work any more)
- Delete all apps

What am I missing? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved for me by updating the phone to the latest available android version.

Answer (score 0):

see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1843837 , especially post #8

quoting:

I finally figured out what "Fast Force Close" app is doing to stop the freeze. It does something rather simple: it basically "hides" the /data/log folder, by moving it aside, and replacing it by a symlink. And this then also, causes Wifi to not connect after a reboot (dunno why)

```
mv /data/log /data/log_backup
ln -s /dev/null /data/log
```

To "disable" the fix, it just does the reverse.

Anyway, this got me thinking that the solution was somehow related to stuff happening in that folder. And one of the things happening in that folder, on a Force Close, is that it receives the output of the dumpstate command:

```
dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

So, my solution for the "Freeze instead of Force Close dialog" issue is to put some files in the /data/log folder, with such permissions that dumpstate can not do its thing.

I found this to solve the issue, but I don't know if there are side effects.

If you want to implement this, you can do it in many ways (e.g. even through terminal emulator or probably some root file explorer). I'm attaching a flashable zip that will do this for you. (see XDA link)

Apart from some boilerplate code, the essential bit is this (in updater-script in the zip):

```
ui_print("Apply fix...");
delete("/data/log/dumpstate_app_error");
delete("/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz");
delete("/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz.tmp");
package_extract_file("placeholder", "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error");
package_extract_file("placeholder", "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz");
package_extract_file("placeholder", "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz.tmp");
set_perm(0, 0, 0400, "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error");
set_perm(0, 0, 0400, "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz");
set_perm(0, 0, 0400, "/data/log/dumpstate_app_error.txt.gz.tmp");
```

Comment: Im having problems flashing it, im getting status 7 :s

Comment: better discuss on XDA. Maybe you need to disable asserts and or signature verification.